# Как выполнить функцию при нажатии enter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как выполнять определенную функцию при нажатии enter в tkinter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно делать так если функция принимает аргументы

```
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event: func(arg1, arg2, ...) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так :

```
try:
    from tkinter import*
except:
    from Tkinter import*
root=Tk()
def func(arg):
    pass
root.bind('<Return>',func)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Если функцию надо привязать к, например entry то так :

```
try:
    from Tkinter import*
except:
    from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
def func(arg):
    return
e=Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Return>',func)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: У Вас может возникнуть ошибка, поскольку func имеет аргумент а в методе bind func не передает никаких аргументов.